# apt upgrade gives "Operation not permitted"

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

While trying to upgrade Ubuntu 21.10 by running `apt upgrade` as root, I get the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.8.1-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/login.1.gz.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/login.1.gz'): Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.8.1-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb
```

Further inspection suggests it may have to do with the extended attributes of `/usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1`.

When running `lsattr -ld /usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/` it outputs:

```
/usr/share/man/zh_CN/man1/   Synchronous_Updates, Immutable, Append_Only, Compression_Requested, Extents
```

Can I safely remove these attributes (I expect them to be there for a reason)?
Or is there some other upgrade command I need to perform?

Comment: I reinstalled the system, since it started crashing consistently and at some point would no longer start.

Comment: I had this problem running apt upgrade. All packages except linux-firmware upgraded fine, but upgrading that package gave me an "Operation not permitted" error opening the .deb, with an "unable to open" message for a file in /lib/firmware. What was odd was that on each attempt it flagged a different file. Two I captured were /lib/firmware/intel/irci_irci_ecr-master_20161208_0213_20170112_1500.bin.dpkg-new and /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode.dpkg-new. Since the problem didn't seem isolated to one file, I ran apt upgrade again and it worked. Not a fix, but a lucky workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're using an antivirus! Disable that antivirus and proceed.

**Note**: I'm pretty sure this is due to McAfee, so, please run every suggested command step by step until the problem is fixed.

1. First, run the following commands to disable any instance of antivirus:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --purge mfedx 
   sudo dpkg --purge mcafeetp 
   sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespaac 
   sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespfileaccess 
   Sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeesp 
   sudo dpkg --purge mcafeert 
   sudo dpkg --purge mfecma 
   sudo dpkg --purge mfert
   ```
2. Remove any antivirus/security/blocker program you're using.
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

---

1. If the upgrade still showed errors, then also run:

   ```
   sudo apt clean 
   sudo apt autoremove 
   sudo dpkg -i ./var/cache/apt/archives*.deb
   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/login_1%3a4.8.1-1ubuntu9_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Now update and upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   ```

---

Still not fixed?

1. If it's still showing errors, I'd recommend reinstalling the packages.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
2. Check if you have all the dependencies installed.

   The package `login` depends on:

   - `libaudit1` (>= 1:2.2.1)
     Dynamic library for security auditing
   - `libc6` (>= 2.33)
     GNU C Library: Shared libraries
   - `libcrypt1` (>= 1:4.1.0)
     `libcrypt` shared library
   - `libpam-modules` (>= 1.1.8-1)
     Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
   - `libpam-runtime`
     Runtime support for the PAM library
   - `libpam0g` (>= 0.99.7.1)
     Pluggable Authentication Modules library

---

If it isn't fixed till now then purge-reinstall the `login` package:

```
sudo dpkg -P login
sudo apt remove --purge login
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install login
```

Feel free to ask me anything in comments or chat.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a virusscanner running. I tried `apt --fix-broken install` but got the same error

Comment: `dpkg -P login` errors out with `this is an essential package; it should not be removed`

Comment: @SergeFonville Have you ran other commands?

Comment: @SergeFonville Let's continue this [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133026/discussion-on-operattion-not-permitted),

Comment: I executed all commands and that gave the same error message.

Comment: @SergeFonville OK! Run `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold login && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @SergeFonville BTW I wrote such a big answer just to hear "It didn't work"? :/ Please provide errors you got, other details about how my answer didn't work? Please avoid extended discussion is comments, let's move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133026/discussion-on-operattion-not-permitted)

Answer (score -2):

`apt` commands require administrator privileges.

You need to preface the command with `sudo`.

You should also run `sudo apt update` before you do anything else in `apt` to make sure that you are working with the current list of software.

For example:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: The OP says they are *"running `apt upgrade` as root"* already - in any case, the error from not being root would be "permission denied" (EACCES) rather than "operation not permitted" (EPERM) I think?